# Selected dates into sql query

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to select two dates in a datepicker and transfer the selected dates into a sql query.

I have a sql query similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Product_sales 
WHERE From_date >= '03-Jan-2013'
AND To_date <= '09-Jan-2013'
```

and I want the dates to be changed to what I select in the datepicker which is the startDate and endDate.

I select the dates in the datepicker and go to another page where I want my result.

How do I put the selected dates into my query?

Comment: ***WHAT*** database is this for? SQL is just the query language - used by many database systems ....

Answer (score 3):

Of course you will want to use parameterized queries:

```
DateTime fromDate = dateTimePickerFrom.Value;
DateTime toDate = dateTimePickerTo.Value;

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Product_sales WHERE From_date >= ? AND To_date <= ?", conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", fromDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", toDate);

        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed from the SQL Server specific `SqlConnection/-Command` to `OldDbConnection/-Command`. Please note that you can't name parameters here, but need to use `?`, but you *can* name them when adding them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your dates for MySQL, which uses the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```
string mySqlDateTime = dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Why do you assume it's MySQL?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar there was a mention of MySQL in the question (or perhaps a comment) that has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your query to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Product_sales 
WHERE From_date >= @Date
AND To_date <= @Date
```

and then when you get the data, you would do something like this:

```
using (MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(cString))
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, c))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", datePicker.Value);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

where `sql` is the query I showed above. Further, I don't know if it's the `Value` property of the `DatePicker` you want, but I *think it is.* If it's not, just substitute the right property.

Comment: Why do you assume it's MySql?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, there was a comment or text in the question that I saw originally that I no longer see. I'm not sure now. Either way, it doesn't change the implementation.

Comment: I was just puzzled, because both you and Andy kept talking about MySQL and to me there was no indication of MySQL being used or asked for. :-)